# What should I do if I have a question on inactive post?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, asking-questions

I recently asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2926317/553404) about gamma function, and Vincent law commented a [link to another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264034/closed-form-expression-for-the-gamma-function-for-complex-numbers-s-aib-with) which stated similar question.

There I found [a link to MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112682/riemann-siegel-function-and-gamma-function).

I visited there, and I came up with some questions about an answer (of Sankyu Kim), because the OP said some statements with doubt that his answer might be incorrect. Also I tried to find Euler- chi function which was mentioned in his answer on google, but I could only find Euler-legandre function, etc.

I checked ChinaHonkong(OP)'s recent activity and Sankyu's recent activity and found out that they haven't been active for years.

Obviously they seem not to reply to my comments.

What should I do? May I ask a new question about someone else's post?

If you want me to post the questions not on MO but Math SE please recommend me.

Thanks!

Comment: I will just point out that [China-Hong Kong's profile](https://mathoverflow.net/users/25947/china-hong-kong?tab=profile) says "Last seen 2 hours ago" and [Sangkyu Kim's profile](https://mathoverflow.net/users/52944/sangkyu-kim?tab=profile) says "Last seen 2 days ago". So it's not exactly true that "they haven't been active for years." (They have not posted anything on MO for some time, but they have visited the site.) But regardless of this, the question about asking clarification of an older post is a reasonable question for MathOverflow Meta.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Oh, I think I had too quickly concluded that they are inactive by seeing Sb's Recent activity in mobile app. Maybe I woke them up this year(they did no actions for a year)?

Comment: @MartinSleziak you gave me hope to wait, thanks:)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Well, do you think it is too trivial to ask "what are properties of euler-chi function?" on mathoverflow?

Comment: Based on what I have seen, yes, it is too trivial: in the post the chi is defined in terms of zeta, and so you would be expected to derive the properties of chi knowing zeta. Your original question has some interest, but do a bit more research before posting it here.  See if you can find a paper or text which approaches the question.  If you can't, someone might be able suggest one. When you do post, indicate not only this meta question but also your original post.  Gerhard "You Might Try Wolfram Alpha" Paseman, 2018.09.27.